Mobile Browser Camera feed to detect/recognise the local image i passed in React JS
I've been trying to detect the image i passed to the 'detectTrigger()' function when the browser camera feed is placed infront of this page.

What i do is pass the image asset local path i want to detect to the detectTrigger().
After running this page(ill run this in my mobile using ngrok), Mobile phone browser camera feed(back camera) will be opened.
I show the mobile camera feed to the image i passed(ill keep them open in my system)
Now camera feed should detect the image shown to it, if the image is same as the image passed to the detectTrigger().

I don't know where im going wrong, the image is not being detected/recognised, can anyone help me in this.
    import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import cv from "@techstark/opencv-js";
    
    
    const AR = () => {
        const videoRef = useRef(null);
        const canvasRef = useRef(null);
        const [modelVisible, setModelVisible] = useState(false);

    const loadTriggerImage = async (url) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; // Handle CORS
            img.src = url;
            img.onload = () => resolve(img);
            img.onerror = (e) => reject(e);
        });
    };

    const detectTrigger = async (triggerImageUrl) => {
        try {
            console.log("Detecting trigger...");
            const video = videoRef.current;
            const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    
            if (video && canvas && video.videoWidth > 0 && video.videoHeight > 0) {
                const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
                canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                const frame = cv.imread(canvas);
    
                const triggerImageElement = await loadTriggerImage(triggerImageUrl);
                const triggerCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                triggerCanvas.width = triggerImageElement.width;
                triggerCanvas.height = triggerImageElement.height;
                const triggerContext = triggerCanvas.getContext("2d");
                triggerContext.drawImage(triggerImageElement, 0, 0);
                const triggerMat = cv.imread(triggerCanvas);
    
                const detector = new cv.ORB();
                const keyPoints1 = new cv.KeyPointVector();
                const descriptors1 = new cv.Mat();
                detector.detectAndCompute(triggerMat, new cv.Mat(), keyPoints1, descriptors1);
    
                const keyPoints2 = new cv.KeyPointVector();
                const descriptors2 = new cv.Mat();
                detector.detectAndCompute(frame, new cv.Mat(), keyPoints2, descriptors2);
    
                const matcher = new cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_HAMMING, true);
                const matches = new cv.DMatchVector();
                matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
    
                const goodMatches = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
                    const match = matches.get(i);
                    if (match.distance < 30) { // Tightened threshold
                        goodMatches.push(match);
                    }
                }
                console.log(`Matches Found: ${matches.size()}, Good Matches: ${goodMatches.length}`);
    
                // Require a minimum number of good matches
                if (goodMatches.length > 10) {
                    console.log("Trigger Image Detected!");
                    // Optional: Verify matches using homography (if necessary)
                    const srcPoints = [];
                    const dstPoints = [];
                    goodMatches.forEach((match) => {
                        srcPoints.push(keyPoints1.get(match.queryIdx).pt.x, keyPoints1.get(match.queryIdx).pt.y);
                        dstPoints.push(keyPoints2.get(match.trainIdx).pt.x, keyPoints2.get(match.trainIdx).pt.y);
                    });
    
                    const srcMat = cv.matFromArray(goodMatches.length, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, srcPoints);
                    const dstMat = cv.matFromArray(goodMatches.length, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, dstPoints);
    
                    const homography = cv.findHomography(srcMat, dstMat, cv.RANSAC, 5);
    
                    if (!homography.empty()) {
                        setModelVisible(true);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Homography failed, no coherent match.");
                        setModelVisible(false);
                    }
    
                    // Cleanup matrices
                    srcMat.delete();
                    dstMat.delete();
                    homography.delete();
                } else {
                    console.log("Trigger Image Not Detected.");
                    setModelVisible(false);
                }
    
                // Cleanup
                frame.delete();
                triggerMat.delete();
                keyPoints1.delete();
                keyPoints2.delete();
                descriptors1.delete();
                descriptors2.delete();
                matcher.delete();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error detecting trigger:", error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const triggerImageUrl = '/assets/pavan-kumar-nagendla-11MUC-vzDsI-unsplash.jpg'; // Replace with your trigger image path

        // Start video feed
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" } })
            .then((stream) => {
                if (videoRef.current) videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error("Error accessing camera:", error));

        // Start detecting trigger at intervals
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => detectTrigger(triggerImageUrl), 500);

        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div
            className="ar"
            style={{
                display: "grid",
                placeItems: "center",
                height: "100vh",
                width: "100vw",
                position: "relative",
            }}
        >
            <div>
                <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted playsInline style={{ width: "100%" }} />
                <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ display: "none" }} />
                {modelVisible && (
                    <div
                        style={{
                            position: "absolute",
                            top: "50%",
                            left: "50%",
                            transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
                            color: "white",
                            fontSize: "24px",
                            background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)",
                            padding: "20px",
                            borderRadius: "10px",
                        }}
                    >
                        Trigger Image Detected! Model Placeholder
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AR;

